# Trying to get data from a button and have a tailored popup with jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I am using a modal dialog opener that I want to open when a user clicks one of a few available buttons.  The buttons all have a different "artist_id" associated with them.  When a button is clicked, I also have a php script that should run and put the user id and artist id in a table that keeps track of the "liking" relationships.  Below is the relevant code:

index.php:

```
//script
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({autoOpen: false, height: 250, width: 400, modal: true});

  $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                       $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog( "open" );

                       $.get('/like_artist.php', {artist_id : $(this).data('artist_id')})
                       .done(function(data) {

                             alert("Data Loaded: " + data.artist_id);

                             });

        });

  });
</script>
```

//button:

```
<button type="button" id="opener" data-artist_id="1">Play My City</button>
```

//dialog content (I would like to have this change based on the button clicked):

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic dialog">
<p>You have just liked ...</p>

<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

like_artist.php: takes a user id and artist id and puts them in the relationship table user_artists

```
<?php 

session_start();
require_once "database.php";
db_connect();
require_once "auth.php";
$current_user = current_user();
include_once("config.php");

    $artist_id = $_GET['artist_id'];

    $user_id = $current_user['id'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `user_artists`
    (`artist_id`, `user_id`)
    VALUES
    (''$artist_id', '$user_id')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

?>
```

The alert I have put in the top script is there to see if I am getting the correct artist_id from the data-artist_id property, but it is not returning anything.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't alert anything or the alert is empty?

Comment: Check the javascript errors on the page, my guess that the data object doesn't have an artist_id, as the data is the content the php gives back, but you didn't return anything.

Comment: $(this).data('artist_id') -> $(this).attr('artist_id') . I don't know if "data" do the same work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning (echoing) anything in `like_artist.php`, naturally your AJAX response will be empty as well.

```
echo json_encode(array('artist_id' => $artist_id));
```

Then you'll have to decode it on the frontend.

Comment: hmm, i tried this on the front end: $.get('/like_artist.php',function(data) {
                             alert("Data Loaded: " + data.artist_id);
                             }, "json");

and it is returning null

Comment: See if the server is returning anything with either Developer Tools (Chrome) or Firebug (Firefox) in the Net tab.

Comment: 1 request: GET like_artist.php

Comment: Response: {"artist_id":null}

Comment: I mean the raw response from the server. You should be able to see it... Maybe you got an error message or something. Have you tried the code I supplied in the answer?

Comment: I did, I included your code in the like_artist.php file.  Under which field are you looking for info?  Where do you see the raw response?

Comment: firefox, i used firebug to get those outputs